# How to auto signOut a firebase user in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a flutter app with firebase as a backend and an authentication,
 now I want the app to have a trial version where the user can signInWithGoogle and use the app with full features ( for like one hour ), and then signs out automatically after that one hour ends.

**SO FAR, I accomplished the following:
1- signIn with google account.

2- add signed in user to** `_trial collection` **with timeStamp.**

```
Future enterTrial() async {
    final UserCredential user = await Auth.instance.googleSignInMethod();
    final User actualUser = user.user;
    try {
        //_trial is a collection for users in Trial Period
      await _trial.doc(actualUser.email).set({.   
        "name": actualUser.displayName,
        "email": actualUser.email,
        "creationDate": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

**WHAT's LEFT:

after one hour from signIn, signOut and move user from** `_trial collection` **to** `_expired collection`.

so that I could check if the user is expired or not.
is there a way to automatically signOut after sometime? or to - periodically - compare creationTime with currentTime and accordingly signOut?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can achive this by using [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) package this provide you a **callback** function in that function you can call your logout method.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, I'll give it a try.

Comment: do you have any idea how to compare tow timestamps?

Comment: just slice the the field which u want to compare